# Labelling variables in regression output (reproducible research)

Tags: r, regression, reproducible-research

I achieve to get nicely formatted regression results using the glm() function and then building a table (myTable).

```
> myTable <- cbind("Estimate" = coef(FulMod), "Std. Error" = summary(FulMod)$coefficients[,2], ,"p value" = summary(FulMod)$coefficients[,4],"OR" = FulMod.coef,"CI"=exp(confint(FulMod)))

> round(myTable,3)
                      Estimate Std. Error p value     OR  2.5 % 97.5 %
(Intercept)            -8.393      1.727   0.000  0.000  0.000  0.006
var1                    0.064      0.018   0.000  1.066  1.031  1.105
as.factor(var2)         0.044      0.015   0.003  1.045  1.016  1.078
relevel(var3,ref=1)2    0.004      0.002   0.028  1.004  1.000  1.008
```

My question is: How can I automatically relabel the variables names that appear in the first column? Until now, I have been using the rownames() function:

```
rownames(myTable)<-c("(Intercept","My Var 1","My Var 2"...
```

However, that's not really flexible. Let's say I update the regression model, I will have to manually change the parameters of the rownames() function. I would prefer a search and replace solution, like "replace 'var1' with 'My Var 1"'.

I checked the structure of myTable and found the gsub() function while searching the web.

```
> str(myTable)
 num [1:6, 1:6] -8.3933 0.06363 0.04442 0.00415 3.1484 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "(Intercept)" "var1"  ...
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "p value" "OR" ...
```

I tried gsub("var1", "My Var 1", myTable) but that messed up the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: `rownames(myTable) <- gsub("var1", "My Var 1", rownames(myTable))` as it's the row names you want to change rather than the table itself.

Comment: Why not change variable names and types before running `glm`?

Comment: @Matt Weller: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. It works great for simle replacements (e.g. "var1"), but I can't get to work for more complex ones like "relevel(as.factor(var2), ref = "no")yes". I tried: rownames(myTable)<-gsub('relevel(as.factor(var2), ref = "no")yes','My var 2',rownames(myTable))

Comment: Talking of reproducible research, you might find [knitr package](http://yihui.name/knitr/) useful.

Comment: You might want to look at something like xtable or stargazer for better control over these kinds of output tables.

Comment: @moabit21 Perhaps update the question to show what you have tried and where it fails.  The error messages will give a pointer to you and others.